# Spring-Boot: Failure on running of a spring-boot restful program

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, jpa

I'm newbie to spring-boot. I have written a very simple restful project to do CRUD actions on an entity and I use jpa and sql server. When I run it, it fails and the error is related to the database and the driver.

I have read almost all of the question related to this error and none of them was the answer.

Here's all information:

```
application.properties:
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=restful;integratedSecurity=true
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.jpa.database=SQL_SERVER
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop

spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=20
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=15
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myweb</groupId>
    <artifactId>restful-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>restful-api</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.2.jre8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.20.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

UserDaoImp.java:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDaoImp implements UserDao {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jt;

    @Override
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        String query = "select all from Users";
        RowMapper<User> rm = new UserRowMapper();
        return jt.query(query, rm);
    }

    @Override
    public User getUser(long id) {
        String query = "select * from Users where Users.ID=?";
        RowMapper<User> rm = new UserRowMapper();
        return jt.queryForObject(query, rm, id);
    }

    @Override
    public User getUser(String name, String lastName) {
        String query = "select * from Users where Users.Name=? and Users.LastName=?";
        RowMapper<User> rm = new UserRowMapper();
        return jt.queryForObject(query, rm, name, lastName);
    }

    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {
        if (!doesUserExist(user)) {
            String query = "insert into Users values(?,?,?);";
            jt.update(query, user.getName(), user.getLastName(), user.getId());

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(User user) {
        String query = "Delete from Users where Users.id=? And Users.Name=? And Users.LastName=?";
        jt.update(query, user.getId(), user.getName(), user.getLastName());
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        if (doesUserExist(user)) {
            String query = "Update Users set Name=?, LastName=? where Users.Id=?";
            jt.update(query, user.getName(), user.getLastName(), user.getId());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean doesUserExist(User user) {
        String query = "select * from Users where Users.Id=? And Users.Name=? And Users.LastName=?";
        RowMapper<User> rm = new UserRowMapper();
        User u = jt.queryForObject(query, rm, user.getId(), user.getName(), user.getLastName());
        if (u == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

ServiceImp.java:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
public class ServiceImp implements Service {

    @Autowired
    private UserDaoImp udi;

    @Override
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return udi.getUsers();
    }

    @Override
    public User getUser(long id) {
        return udi.getUser(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {
        udi.addUser(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(User user) {
        udi.deleteUser(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(User user) {
        udi.updateUser(user);
    }
}
```

---

Exception:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

at the end it says:

```
Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Note: One thing That i can't figure out is that i have registered dependency for sql server driver in **pom.xml**, but the library doesn't exist in **External Library**.

Regards

Comment: Which database are you trying to use along with this app?

Comment: It's in the question! Sql server

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

1) Right click on Project.

2) Maven -> Update Project

3) Refresh the project again.

Or try with other dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc4 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

`

Comment: i searched for this version already, but couldn't find it in _mvnrepository.com_.Now I copied, and it is saying that can't find this version

Comment: `<!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>`
Have you correctly entered this???

Comment: Alternatively you can try this [Tutorial](https://springframework.guru/configuring-spring-boot-for-microsoft-sql-server/)

Comment: The problem is not about the line you mentioned. I already read that tutorial. Thank you

Comment: Try removing `JPA` dependency if you are using `mssql-jdbc` dependency.

Comment: Can't remove it! I use JPA features in the program